# What is the right way to use a QStateMachine for a text adventure game?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, databases, qt

I have seen a couple topics about this already but they were a bit vague for me so I decided to make this. I'm working on a little adventure game just for fun in Qt, its basically just text on the screen and the player inputs commands into a line edit widget which I then process and do the related action/event. Thing is, I am a little confused on how to approach this. I don't want to dig myself a hole by manually coding in lots of commands and events per room because it seems to just be a pain later on. So then I thought about using some sort of database to store the information but which one should I use? I would love some advice from people who have tried something similar.

And here, these pictures are a rough outline of what I am trying to do.

[image: Flowchart of states]

[image: Level tiles]

Edit: I should add, the tiles for the level basically work like this. The light gray is a direction the player can move in, the dark gray parts are walls and the colors are various different actions you can do.

I don't particularly care for code, but I would like suggestions on what tools to use for this and maybe how to set them up right.

Comment: Edited images in for you

Comment: What is the actual question, here?  The only one you ask explicitly (buried in the middle of all the text) is "which database should I use?" Which is a 'which technology to use' question, which is off-topic here as per the [FAQ].  Am I missing another implicit question?